# PDF's in SharePoint 2010

Tags: pdf, crawling

With SharePoint 2010, how can you make sure that PDF's are indexed and that they do not have a generic icon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is listed in several places on the interwebs. But I suggest look at this official KB article: SharePoint 2010 - Configuring Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357.

Comment: Thanks Wictor-  Any good sources for configuring the same with the FoxIt PDF filter?  According to Jie Li, it crushes the Adobe ifilter performance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/02/09/pdf-ifilter-test-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Jie blogged about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2009/10/20/index-and-search-pdf-files-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

Comment: Hi Wictor - could installing this iFilter blow out a full crawl ..from say hours to over a day? This is what we are seeing after installing it.

Comment: Yes - you need to do a full crawl.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, Fast Search for SharePoint (client access licence included in SharePoint Enterprise), allow indexing PDF files without installing an ifilter.

Edit: CAL is included, not server

Comment: Fast Search is not included in Enterprise. It requires the purchase of its own license. But it does index PDF files natively.

Comment: CAL are included, but you are correct there is also a server licence. However, most of the cost is in CAL.